# How to derive the power series of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ followed the footstep of Euler

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am reading Euler's "[Introduction to analysis of the infinite](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/introductiontoanalysisvol1.htm)", chapter 8, page at the end of page 208, beginning of page 209 and came across his derivation of the power series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. I try hard to follow his steps but fail flat.

He wrote as followed:

$\sin(nz)=\dfrac{n}{1}(\cos(z))^{n-1}\sin(z)-\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\cos(z)^{n-3}(\sin(z))^{3}+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{5!}(\cos(z))^{n-5}(\sin(z)^5 .etc$

$\cos(nz)=\cos(z)^{n}-\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}(\cos(z))^{n-2}(\sin(z))^{2}+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}\cos(z)^{n-4}(\sin(z)^4.etc$

He stated:

> Let the arc of z be infinitely small; there will be $\sin(z)=z$ and $\cos(z)=1$; moreover $n$ shall be an infinitely great number, so that the arc $nz$ shall be of finite magnitude, for example $nz=v$; on account of $\sin(z)=z=\dfrac{v}{n}$ there becomes

> $\cos(v)=1-\dfrac{v^2}{2!}+\dfrac{v^4}{4!}-\dfrac{v^6}{6!}+.etc$

> $\sin(v)=v-\dfrac{v^3}{3!}+\dfrac{v^5}{5!}-\dfrac{v^7}{7!}+.etc$

I have a couple of questions:

1. What does it mean when he says $z$ be infinitely small and $sin(z)=z$? On the interval $(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$, we have the equality $\sin(z)<z$. Besides $-1\leq\sin(z)\leq1$ $\forall z$, does it mean that $z$ approach $0$, because obviously $\sin(z)=z$ only when $z=0$. This makes sense when $\cos(0)=1$, as he stated. Also, what does he mean when he said $n$ is infinitely large?
2. I've tried to substitute $\sin(z)=z=\dfrac{v}{n}$ and $\cos(z)=1$ but I could not eliminate the whole bunch of $n(n-1)(n-2)$ (for $\sin(nz)$) or $n(n-1)$ (for $\cos(nz)$) or the likes to arrive at the final power series for both functions. Here are what I've got.

$\sin(nz)=\dfrac{n\cdot z}{1}-\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}z^3+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{5!}z^5+ .etc$

Obviously the first term is $v$, but what about the rest of the terms?

$\cos(nz)=1-\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}z^2+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}z^4- .etc$

Obviously because I don't know what is the value of $n$ so I can't make them varnish. Could you help me here? Thank you so much!

Comment: I notice that if $n=1$, then all the falling factorial of will varnish, but this doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think he uses that $n$ large implies $n(n-1)\approx n^2$, then replace your $z$'s in the substitutions with $\frac{v}{n}$.

Comment: $sin(z) ≈ z$ and $cos(z) ≈ 1$ are the [small angle approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) (to first order). When you plug them in, using the fact that n large as @RyanK suggested, this gives the derived result.

Comment: @legionwhale Could you post a fuller answer with some explanations. I am still at a loss.  How does making $n$ infinitely large can make things like $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$ disappear?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Consider the term in your equation for $\sin$ $$\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{5!}z^5$$ substituting $z = v/n$ gives $$\dfrac{v^5n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{n^5\cdot 5!}$$ now we have $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)\approx n^5$ for large $n$ so we end up with $$\frac{v^5}{5!}$$

Comment: @RyanK But $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)=n^5-15n^4+85n^3-225n^2+274n-120$. Isn't that a huge difference from $n^5$? What value of $n$ can be large enough for this approximation to be correct?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(n−1)(n−2)(n−3)(n−4)}{n^5} = 1$ He states that $n$ is thought to be infinitely large.

Comment: @RyanK Suddenly with limit, I get the picture. Thank you, that is clear enough. However, I still have one question. He said that $z$ is infinite small, so that the arc $nz$ is a finite magnitude. What does it mean? That $z$ approaches $0$ while $n$ tends to positive infinity?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Yes, I think so. It's not very rigorous, but this was the 18th C. By the way, you have copied down the series incorrectly. The sign of each term should be alternating +, -, +, etc.

Comment: @legionwhale in my comment or in my main thread? I will fix them!

Comment: I am not going to make any claims about the consistency of the given proof, I would imagine (myself included) that many mathematicians would hesitate to use this as an actual proof. But essentially it $\textit{seems to be}$ true that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{z\to 0}\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{5!}(\cos(z))^{n-5}(\sin(v/n))^5 = \frac{v^5}{5!}$$ I would not claim however that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{z\to 0}nz = v$ for some $v\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JamesWarthington the first time you wrote the series for cos(nz) and sin(nz) in the question. It is correct in the later series.

Comment: @legionwhale thanks for pointing out, fixed!

Comment: @RyanK I think Euler's argument is based on numerous calculations and manipulations. Math in his time is all about manipulating algebraic symbols and numerical approximating. Euler introduces the infinite Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ before the introduction of differentiation so it is understandable that he needs to derive it in other ways.

Comment: @RyanK what is the effect on $cos^{n-5}(z)$ as n increases to infinity. The function will just be from $0$ to $1$ when $n-5$ is even, and between $-1$ and $1$ for $n-5$ being odd. Am I correct?

Comment: If you take the limit as $z\to 0$ first, then $\cos^{n-5}(z)\to 1$

Comment: @RyanK Is there a way to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{z\to\infty}nz=v$ for some $v$ in $\mathbb{R}$. This is the weakness of Euler's proof, right?